# DAO NullPointerException in Spring Hibernate Service Layer

Tags: java, spring, hibernate

I am relatively new to using the combination of Spring and Hibernate and have a problem I cannot seem to figure out.  Inside the service there are a number of DAOs - each defined in my applicationContext.xml file.  All but one of these DAOs are instantiated but one of them is null and I can't figure out why just that one would be null.  The one DAO is null is the RelationshipDAO.  Here's my code...

Service Layer:

```
public class LocalReadServiceImpl extends implements LocalReadService {

private CallDao callDao;
private CallSectionDao callSectionDao;
private CaseClassDao caseClassDao;
private ReferralDao referralDao;
private RelationshipDao relationshipDao;

public Relationship retRelationshipByCode(String relationshipCode) {
    Relationship relationship =(Relationship)relationshipDao.findRelationshipByCode(relationshipCode);
    return relationship;
}
```

DAO:

```
public class RelationshipDao extends HibernateDaoSupport{

public RelationshipDao() {
    super(Relationship.class);
}

public Relationship findRelationshipByCode(String relationshipCode) {
    Criteria criteria = getSession().createCriteria(Relationship.class);
    criteria.add(Restrictions.eq("relationshipCode",relationshipCode)); 
    Relationship relationship = (Relationship)criteria.uniqueResult();
    return relationship;
}
}
```

applicationContext.xml

```
<bean id="localReadService" class="org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionProxyFactoryBean"
    parent="txProxyTemplate">
    <property name="target">
        <bean class="redmane.hmsCallcenter.service.impl.LocalReadServiceImpl">
            <property name="callDao" ref="callDao" />
            <property name="callSectionDao" ref="callSectionDao" /> 
            <property name="caseClassDao" ref="caseClassDao" />     
            <property name="referralDao" ref="referralDao" />       
            <property name="relationshipDao" ref="relationshipDao" />   
        </bean>
    </property>
</bean>

<bean id="baseDaoTemplate" abstract="true">
    <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory" />
</bean>

<bean id="callDao" class="redmane.hmsCallcenter.dao.CallDao"
    parent="baseDaoTemplate" />
<bean id="callSectionDao"
    class="redmane.hmsCallcenter.dao.CallSectionDao"
    parent="baseDaoTemplate" />     
<bean id="caseClassDao"
    class="redmane.hmsCallcenter.dao.CaseClassDao"
    parent="baseDaoTemplate" /> 
<bean id="referralDao" class="redmane.hmsCallcenter.dao.ReferralDao"
    parent="baseDaoTemplate" />     
<bean id="relationshipDao"
    class="redmane.hmsCallcenter.dao.RelationshipDao"
    parent="baseDaoTemplate" />
```

I've got no clue why all the other DAOs would be instantiated but that one RelationshipDAO would not.

Any insight would be greatly appreciated.  If more detail is needed please let me know.

Comment: Good idea, would be to include the stack trace.

Comment: Include the stack trace and the full code of your service, that is including your setters..

Comment: The log file will contain initialization messages from spring that will tell you what went right and wrong. Your code snippets don't include the package statement so I can't tell if there is a mismatch.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This turned out to be an issue with the configuration XML files not being complete so all of the objects were not getting created by Spring.  Once we corrected the XML files the problem resolved itself.